# Layered architecture in Java

Tags: java

I want to simulate the instructor, course and category sections of a website using java, in a layered architecture. I don't want the course name to repeat, but even though the course names are different, it is constantly

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Course name cannot be the same! at business.CoursesManager.add(CoursesManager.java:28) at Main.main(Main.java:32)`

I get an error. I would appreciate if you could tell me where is the mistake in my code.

**CoursesManager:**

```
package business;

import core.logging.IBaseLogger;
import dataAccess.ICoursesDao;
import entities.Courses;

import java.util.List;

public class CoursesManager {

    private ICoursesDao coursesDao;
    private IBaseLogger[] loggers;
    private List<Courses> coursesList;

    public CoursesManager(ICoursesDao coursesDao,IBaseLogger[] loggers,List<Courses> coursesList){
        this.coursesDao = coursesDao;
        this.loggers = loggers;
        this.coursesList = coursesList;
    }

    public void add(Courses courses) throws Exception {
        if (courses.getCoursePrice() < 0) {
            throw new Exception("Course price cannot be less than 0!");
        }

            for (Courses checkCourses : coursesList) {

                if (courses.getCourseName().equals(checkCourses.getCourseName())) {
                throw new Exception("Course name cannot be the same!");
            }
        }

        coursesDao.add(courses);
        coursesList.add(courses);

        for (IBaseLogger logger : loggers) {
            logger.log(courses.getCourseName());
        }
    }


    }
```

**Main:**

```
import business.CategoriesManager;
import business.CoursesManager;
import core.logging.DatabaseLogger;
import core.logging.FileLogger;
import core.logging.IBaseLogger;
import core.logging.MailLogger;
import dataAccess.HibernateDao;
import dataAccess.JdbcDao;
import entities.Categories;
import entities.Courses;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Courses course1 = new Courses(1,"Java",10);
        Courses course2 = new Courses(2,"C#",200);
        Courses course3 = new Courses(3,"Html&Css",300);

        List<Courses> coursesList = new ArrayList<>();
        coursesList.add(course1);
        coursesList.add(course2);
        coursesList.add(course3);


        IBaseLogger[] loggers = {new FileLogger(),new DatabaseLogger(),new MailLogger()};

        CoursesManager coursesManager = new CoursesManager(new HibernateDao(),loggers,coursesList);
        coursesManager.add(course1);

        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

        Categories categories1 = new Categories("Back-end");
        Categories categories2 = new Categories("Mobile");
        Categories categories3 = new Categories("Front-end");

        List<Categories> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add(categories1);
        categories.add(categories2);
        categories.add(categories3);



        CategoriesManager categoriesManager = new CategoriesManager(new JdbcDao(),loggers,categories);
        categoriesManager.add(categories1);





    }
}
```

I did create CoursesManager class and algorithms but it doesnt work. Can anyone tell me which part is wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: Which line is `CoursesManager.java:28`?

Comment: You already pass your List with the 3 courses to your manager in the constructor and then later you try to add the first course again. In other words there is nothing wrong and the error that you are trying to add a dulicate course is because you are in fact trying to add a duplicate course.

Comment: @Jens The one with `throw new Exception`

Comment: Hint: often it is better (helpful) to have more data in the exception: in this case at least the name of the *offending* `Course` (`throw new Exception("Course name cannot be the same! Name: " + courses.getCourseName());` or `throw new Exception("The course list already contains a course with that name: " + courses.getCourseName());`)

Answer (score 0):

You create a coursesList with 3 courses (in the beginning of the main function).
This list is passed to the course manager that stores that very same list.
After that at line 32 of the main you try to add course1 to the course manager.
The method finds a course with the very same name already present and therefore throws an exception.

Comment: I already set up the algorithm I tried to set up, I understood better when you explained it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this answer resolves your problem, you might consider accepting it.